# DecimalPad has Comma rather than Dot

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added textfield and keyboard is `DecimalPad`.

However, in the keyboard I see `,` (comma) rather than `.` (dot).

[image]

**EDIT:**

I see some comments below points that U.S. uses `comma` rather than `dot`.

Here is a screenshot from [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/deals).

[image]

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the locale of the device? I think in some cultures commas are used in place of periods

Comment: How could I able to make it  `.` ? I believe that is common-sense for all over the world.

Comment: No, the `.` is not common-sense for all over the world. In many locales around the world, the `,` is used as the decimal separator. You do not want to change it. Changing it will only confuse users of your app that expect the comma. If this is from your iPhone and you want a period instead of a comma, set your iPhone's region properly so you see normal settings for your locale.

Comment: But I want to use `.` for sure and looking to change `comma` to `dot`. Is it possible?

Comment: As mentioned by @rmaddy, change the locale of your device and you'll see the `dot`

Comment: @hotspring Let's clarify your goal here. Do you personally, when you run the app on your iPhone, want to see the period instead of the comma? Or are you talking about an app your are writing and you want all users, no matter what they should see, to see a period?

Comment: I want to see `dot` rather than `comma` in the `decimalpad` no matter where app users use the application.

Comment: Can you explain why you wish to confuse the users of your app with the wrong decimal separator? What is your goal for this? Understanding why you want to do this will make it easier to provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: So, just implement one, you can even use an emoji as a comma if you like. It's not that difficult.

Comment: I personally think commas are a completely stupid thing to use as decimal separators, but there are lots of countries (particularly European countries if I'm not mistaken) that do use commas and will be confused and/or annoyed by a full stop; it would be a bad idea to make your app _always_ use a full stop.

Comment: @rmaddy, @matthewLuiHK, @Clonkex I know a lot of applications (my competitors with $20-30 million investments) use formatter on the textfield input while user type, such as `@"%.2lf"`. However, instead of adding `formatter` on the textfield, I would like to give this option directly to the user via keyboard. do not you think it is legitimate request.

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying about your competitors but that is irrelevant. Users expect numbers, dates, times, etc. to be entered and viewed in their own local customs and formats. It's a terrible user experience to force your own ideas of how they should be formatted. Respect your users and their locale. Make them happy, not confused.

Comment: @rmaddy, I am testing this `Decimalpad` in U.S. and I have just checked `ebay` website, they also use `dot` rather than `comma`. I have even added this screenshot in my question. I wonder what I am missing?

Comment: In the U.S., the period is the standard decimal separator. So that's fine. No one has stated that the U.S. uses a comma for the decimal separator.

Comment: Ok, then why I am seeing comma in the `decimalpad` even I am in the U.S.

Comment: Either you done something specific in your app or the settings of your iPhone are not set properly. What do you have for "Region" on the "Language & Region" screen of the Settings app on your iPhone?

Comment: I did not even touch that section, everything is left to be default. And I have just checked and it shows `English`.

Comment: Asked for the "Region" setting, not the "Language" setting.

Comment: Yes you are totally right @rmaddy, thank you so much for catching up. It was set to another country. Then now I wonder if a user like me uses this app with different country format, then how do you handle this input? Is there a standard way of handling? For example, he enters 2,46 but it should be converted into 2.46 or vice versa...

Comment: A user will enter it in the same format it should be viewed. So your example isn't valid. Use a `NumberFormatter` to parse number strings entered by a user and to display numbers as strings to the user. Then everyone is happy.

Comment: Ok, please add an answer below then I will upvote and mark as an answer. Thanks a lot for putting your time here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Users expect numbers (and dates, times, and other information) to be entered and viewed in their own local format. iOS takes care of this based on their locale. An app should honor these settings.

A comma appears on the number pad when the user's device is set to a region (which affects their locale) that normally uses a comma as the decimal separator. Other symbols (such as a period) will appear depending on the user's locale.

When writing an app that accepts number entry and displays numbers to the user, it is best to use `NumberFormatter` to convert the entered strings into numeric data types and to convert numeric data type into strings. This ensures users can enter and view numbers (and dates, etc.) in the format they normally use in their every day life.

As it turned out, your own iPhone had an unexpected Region setting that caused the comma to appear on the number pad instead of your own expectation of a period. This appears to have led to some confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for resolving this conflict and adding further explanation to make it crystal clear.